# how to avoid filling the RAM when doing multiprocessing in R (future)?

Tags: r, multithreading, multiprocessing, purrr

I am using `furrr` which is built on top of `future`.

I have a very simple question. I have a list of files, say `list('/mydata/file1.csv.gz', '/mydata/file1.csv.gz')` and I am processing them in parallel with a simple function that loads the data, does some filtering stuff, and write it to disk.

In essence,  my function is

```
processing_func <- function(file){
  mydata <- readr::read_csv(file)
  mydata <- mydata %>% dplyr::filter(var == 1)
  data.table::fwrite(mydata, 'myfolder/processed.csv.gz')
  rm()
  gc()
}
```

and so I am simply running

`listfiles %>% furrr::future_map(., processing_func(.x))`

This works, but despite my `gc()` and `rm()` calls, the RAM keeps filling up until the session crashes.

What is the conceptual issue here? Why would some residual objects remain somehow in memory when I explicitly discard them?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know without a replicable example, but `rm()` is not doing anything for you. You need to tell `rm()` what to remove. For example `rm(mydata)`.

Comment: damn!!!! is it that simple???

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: I am trying right now :)

Comment: If running `n` instances of R causes you to run out of memory, try `n-1` or `n-2` instances of R. Doing things in parallel *can* decrease run-time, but *always* increases CPU and memory usage. (Or is there something else I'm missing in your workflow?)

Comment: In a use case presented above I would go with grep, piping, awk, etc. rather than R. Unless filter is more complex.

Comment: interesting. can we use awk from R?

Answer (score 5):

You can try using a [`callr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.callr/vignettes/future.callr.html) future plan, it may be less memory hungry.
As quoted from the `future.callr` vignette

> When using callr futures, each future is resolved in a fresh background R session which ends as soon as the value of the future has been collected. In contrast, multisession futures are resolved in background R worker sessions that serve multiple futures over their life spans. The advantage with using a new R process for each future is that it is that the R environment is guaranteed not to be contaminated by previous futures, e.g. memory allocations, finalizers, modified options, and loaded and attached packages. The disadvantage, is an added overhead of launching a new R process

```
library("future.callr")
plan(callr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using 64-bit R on Windows, R is only bound to RAM by default. You can use memory.limit() to increase the amount of memory your r session can use. The line "memory.limit(50*1024)" would allow your R session to use 50GB of memory. Also, R automatically calls gc() whenever it's running low on space, so that line isn't helping you.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure if memory.limit() will help you then, let me know!?

Answer (score 0):

With future multisession:

```
future::plan(multisession)
processing_func <- function(file){
  readr::read_csv(file) |> 
    dplyr::filter(var == 1) |> 
    data.table::fwrite('...csv.gz')
  gc()
}
listfiles |> purrr::walk(processing_func)
```

Note that I am

1. Not creating any variables in `processing_func` so there is nothing to `rm`
2. Using `purrr::walk` not `map`, as we don't need resolved value.
3. Using `gc()` inside the future.

Passing files to functions in futures is a nice way to parrallelize things. I also like to use multicore instead of multisession to share some objects from the parent environment.

It seems like these sessions run out of memory if you aren't careful. A gc call in the future function seems to help pretty often.