# mlr3 tuning: Error cannot allocate vector of size n Mb

Tags: mlr3

I always hit the memory limit when I try to tune a model with mlr3 and I get the follow error (Error cannot allocate vector of size n Mb). This happens even when I remove all unneeded objects and try to minimize memory use to the lowest possible.

The tuning works with a small resample (changing resample method from cv to holdout). Is there a way to get around this?

see relevant code below

```
inner_cv  = rsmp("cv", folds = 10)

preproc  = po("imputemedian", affect_columns = selector_type("numeric")) %>>%
           po("imputemode",   affect_columns = selector_type("factor"))  %>>% 
           po("scale") %>>%
           po("encode", method = "one-hot") 

para_mod = AutoTuner$new(learner   = as_learner(preproc  %>>% 
                                                lrn("surv.parametric",  
                                                    type = "aft", dist = "lognormal")),
                        resampling = inner_cv,
                        measure    = msr("surv.cindex"),
                        terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 200),
                        tuner      = tnr("irace"))} 

future::plan("multisession")
para_mod$train(task)
```

Comment: Can you give us example code where this happens? Hard to say what the problem is without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, I updated my posted with the relevant code

Comment: What's the size of your data set? Does it work without `future::plan("multisession")`?

Comment: @be-marc my data is not big (800 subjects with 61 features) and I reduced it to 800 by 30 but that did not solve the problem. I did notice the memory use is significantly less without  future::plan("multisession") by 6-10 folds (1 GB without vs 10 GB with multisession).

Comment: I used `tsk("actg")` and `lrn("surv.xgboost", eta = to_tune(1e-4, 1, logscale = TRUE))` and could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am aware of large memory usage by future from other projects but I did not encounter them with mlr3 yet.

Comment: @be-marc, do you think using callr to start fresh R session with clean memory would help? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Usually, "multisession" and "callr" need more memory than "multicore". You can use "callr" with `future::plan("callr")`. You can also try to limit the number of workers `future::plan("multicore", workers = 2)`.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `tsk("actg")` and `lrn("surv.xgboost", eta = to_tune(1e-4, 1, logscale = TRUE))`?

Comment: @be-marc, I will try it and let you know. plan("multicore") does not work on windows (https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/futures.html), does it?. 
I tried to set_threads() but it does not seem to work as well. 
this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57280339/how-to-avoid-filling-the-ram-when-doing-multiprocessing-in-r-future) says less memory used with callr.

Comment: @be-marc, after investigating, I can tell you that the problem occurs only when tuning the "surv.parametric."  Both future::plan("callr") and future::plan("multisession") work fine for all other models but not for "surv.parametric" I always encounter the problem unless I don't do future::() which is only slower